# How to use <picture></picture> tag in featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

In my WordPress site 5.5.1 version so, we uploading jpeg images so we want to page speed for upload webp images. Webp images are not supported by a few browsers. so how to switch images format like this in WordPress

Comment: I'd start by looking at webp plugins and see if any of these will replace your featured image with webp for you. If not, you'll probably have to edit your theme to add support I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

You should add fallback to the webp img tag. In the attached link are some strategies, most relevant is this:

```
 <picture>
    <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
 </picture>
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/